# Massive .htaccess Redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I got some problem on redirecting something.

I tried to use Redirect 301 /link/link/link to /link/link

Is there a way to make it more easier coz there are 100+ links I need to redirect.
Like this 
/blog/category/energy-savings/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing

/blog/category/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/

/blog/category/uncategorized/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/about

/blog/category/uncategorized/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/about

/blog/category/uncategorized/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing

/blog/category/uncategorized/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/about

/blog/category/water-conservation/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing

/blog/category/water-conservation/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/plumbing/about

To the Homepage?

Thanks

Comment: To summarize your question in one word: "plumbing"

Comment: Perhaps there is a bigger problem with why you would have links that have text being repeated forever in them.

Answer (score 0):

The directive:

```
Redirect 301 /link/link/link /link/link
```

Doesn't do what you think it does. It's mapping to nodes together, meaning a request for:

```
/link/link/link/foo/bar.html
```

gets redirected to:

```
/link/link/foo/bar.html
```

So maybe you need to fix that. You could try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/link/link/link/?$ /link/link
```

so the nodes aren't connected like in the `Redirect` directive. As for trying to "fix" this problem of yours, you can try:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\4/ /
```

This redirects anything that looks like: `/blah1/blah2/blah3/same/same/same/` etc. to the homepage at `/`. The `\4` matches the 4th path in the URI, so if anything after the 3rd path repeats, then it redirects.